# Prove the generalization of Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$
1+nx \le (1+x)^n, \forall x \ge-2, \forall n \in \Bbb N
$$

When proving this:

$P(1): 1+n(-2) \le (1+(-2))^n =>$ Let $n = 1$, then $-1 \le -1$ which is true.

$P(n+1): ...$ This part I know how to do, but my question is if the only difference is that the -2 works just as the -1 in the for all x?

Comment: Do you consider 0 as a Natural number here?

Comment: You're right I should start at 1

Comment: You should start at $1$ with: Let $x \ge -2$, then we have $1+nx = 1+x = (1+x)^1 = (1+x)^n$, which proves the base case for all $x \ge -2$. Instead of just proving the base case for $x = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of attacking the Bernoulli inequality is via a geometric sum. The formula for geometric sum gives
$$
(1+x)^n-1=\bigl[1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+\cdots+(1+x)^{n-1}\bigr]x.
$$ 
If $x>0$ then we have $n$ terms inside the square bracket that are all at least $1$, and hence the right hand side is $\geq nx$.

If $-2\leq x\leq0$ then $-1\leq 1+x\leq1$. Hence $-1\leq(1+x)^k\leq 1$ for all $k\geq 1$, which implies that the sum inside the brackets is bounded by $n$, i.e.
$$
\bigl[1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+\cdots+(1+x)^{n-1}\bigr]\leq n.
$$
Multiplying this with $x$, *which is non-positive*, gives
$$
\bigl[1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+\cdots+(1+x)^{n-1}\bigr]x\geq nx,
$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take this approach of proving the inequality:

Expand $$(1+x)^n= 1+nx+ \sum_{i=2}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^i $$$$\leq 1+nx$$ for $x>0$.

Now when $-1<x<0$,
$$(1-x)^n= 1-nx+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}x^i$$ Here you can see that the coefficients of the subsequent terms are smaller from the earlier ones. This implies the sum will be some positive number.

So we can say that   $$(1-x)^n\geq 1-nx$$ for $-1<x<0$.

Hence we can say that $$(1+nx)\leq (1+x)^n$$

Comment: would you please explain the last step? how did you get the result for $x<0$ ?

Comment: @Nizar If you expand $(1-x)^n$ you will see that after the coefficients of $x^i$'s start becoming smaller and smaller. You will also notice that the coefficient of $x^2$ will be greater that coefficient of $x^3$ and coefficient of $x^4$ larger that $x^5$ . When we take the sum it will give me a positive number.

Comment: The inequality $0< x< -1$ looks weird....

Comment: Sorry typo. I will edit it

Comment: I am writing another answer with one more method of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this (for $0\leq r\leq1$) by the weighted A-M and G-M inequality.

Let $a_1,a_2$ be positive constants(weights in this case) on $1,1+x$ . Now using weighted AM -GM inequality:

$$\frac{a_1+(1+x)a_2}{a_1+a_2} \geq \sqrt[a_1+a_2]{(1+x)^{a_2}}$$

The left hand side after a few algebraic manipulations becomes $$1+\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}x$$

And by the law of exponents the right hand side becomes ${(1+x)^{\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}}}$. So now the inequality becomes $$1+\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}x \geq {(1+x)^{\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}}}$$.

Let $\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}=r$

So the inequality becomes $$1+rx\geq (1+x)^r$$